# Cannot get past log in screen after restoring backup

Tags: 14.04, login, chown

I recently restored my `/home/main-account` directory from a backup hard disk. After rebooting I can't get past the log in screen for this account. I had copied all the data using an alt account and it turned out that the ownership of the files had changed to my alt account. So I ran `chown -R main-acccount:main-account /home/main-account` and changed them back. But I still can't get past the log in screen.

What should I do?

Note: After entering the password, the screen goes black for a second and then returns to the log in screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unity, run the following command:

```
sudo rm -R /home/main-account/.config/gnome*
suso rm -R /home/main-account/.gnome*
```

you should now be able to login

If you still can't login, run `dmesg` and see if there are any errors listed that can help.

Comment: I use gnome. `dmesg` didn't give any helpful information.

Comment: @user2604706 okay, there's the answer for gnome

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all your snapshots. If you recently did a timeshift bakup, open a terminal and run sudo rm -rf /timeshift